# how to sort apache directory listing in last modified order

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, apache-2.4

```
# SET DISPLAY ORDER
IndexOrderDefault Descending Name
```

the above value is used to sort directory listing in decending name value how can i create the similiar results for sorting the directory in last modified order.i am using .htaccess.please don't show the alternative ways

```
# SET DISPLAY ORDER
IndexOrderDefault last modified
```

specify the default directory display order:

here is what my .htaccess file look like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
 # Disable server signature
 ServerSignature Off
```

Comment: Your choice of `Options -Indexes` completely disables automatic index generation...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First of all: my pet peeve, quoted from from the [manual on .htaccess](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexorderdefault) files:

> You should **avoid using .htaccess files completely** if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using .htaccess files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a .htaccess file is better set in a Directory block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

Second, [more reading](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexorderdefault) of the manual is also useful:

> The `IndexOrderDefault` directive is used in combination with the `FancyIndexing` index option.

Translation: include the `FancyIndexing` option in the [`IndexOptions`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions) directive.
Then right below that in the manual:

> **IndexOrderDefault takes two arguments**. The first must be either **Ascending or Descending**, indicating the direction of the sort. The second argument must be one of the keywords Name, **Date**, Size, or Description...

That results in the following:

```
<Directory /some/path>
   # Disable .htaccess files for performance:
   AllowOverride none

   # Enable automatic index generation for directories without a DirectoryIndex file 
   # and sort them by date:
   Options +Indexes 
   IndexOptions FancyIndexing
   IndexOrderDefault Descending Date
</Directory>
```

Comment: hello sir you say using htaccess may lead to slow page load but personally i haven't noticed any diff in load time before or after.

Comment: When AllowOverride enables the use of .htaccess files, httpd will look in every directory for .htaccess files. Thus, permitting .htaccess files causes a performance hit, whether or not you actually even use them! Also, the .htaccess file is loaded **every time a document** is requested.
Apache must look for .htaccess files in all higher-level directories, in order to have a full complement of directives that it must apply. If a file is requested out of a directory /www/htdocs/example, httpd must look for these too: /.htaccess
/www/.htaccess
/www/htdocs/.htaccess
/www/htdocs/example/.htaccess